# ExtJS4 - Outline appearing around Submit button for form

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a `fileuploadfield` button that has an outline of a white box appearing behind it. Is there a way to remove this?

It seems to only be an issue in Extjs4.

**Code**

```
items: [{
   xtype: 'form',
   name: 'upload_form',
   border: false,
   items: {
      text: 'File Upload',
      xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
      name: 'upload_btn',
      buttonText: 'Upload File...',
      buttonOnly: true,
      hideLabel: true,
      allowBlank: false,
      clearOnSubmit: false,
    }
 }]
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rkn)

[image: Picture]

Comment: The fileuploadfield MUST be inside a form? if you remove the form and put the fileuploadfield directly inside the toolbar this "white space" will be gone, I think this problem has to do with form padding/margin or something like this

Comment: @MatheusHatje I'm using the form to submit an excel file to a REST endpoint and this functionality does not work currently without the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you must have the `fileuploadfield` inside a form, my workaround was to use a `bodyStyle` configuration in the form, set the `background-color` to transparent, and a `margin-top` to re-center the `fileuploadfield`.

Check out the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2rko)